# MS Access VBA - Recordset SQL Not returning correct amount

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have VBA code that queries a table. The Query view in MS Access returns the correct results, however the vba returns a different result.

Table called tbl_ADMIN_CLASS_INFO

```
Client_ID | POLICY_GROUP   
12345a    | 1  
12345a    | 2    
12345a    | 2    
12345a    | 2    
12345a    | 2
```

Column Definitions from Table:

```
CLIENT_ID = Text  
POLICY_GROUP = Number
```

---

VBA

```
Public Sub NextPageControl()  
Dim dbs                 As Database  
Dim rst                 As Recordset  
Dim CurrentTableName    As String  
Dim CurrentFormName     As String  
Dim NextPageSQL         As String  

Dim CurrentPage         As Form  
Dim LastRecord          As Integer  
Dim Nextpage            As Integer  

Dim TestPolicy          As Long  
Dim TestClient          As String  

TestPolicy = Forms!frm_ADMIN_CLASS_INFO.POLICY_GROUP  'Stepping Through Code shows 12345a  
TestClient = Forms!frm_ADMIN_CLASS_INFO.CLIENT_ID 'Stepping Through Code shows 2 


CurrentTableName = Screen.ActiveForm.RecordSource  
CurrentFormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name  

Set CurrentPage = Screen.ActiveForm  
Set dbs = CurrentDb  


NextPageSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & CurrentTableName & " WHERE ((POLICY_GROUP = " & TestPolicy & ") AND (CLIENT_ID = '" & TestClient & "'))"  
Debug.Print NextPageSQL  

 Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(NextPageSQL, dbOpenDynaset)  

 MsgBox rst.RecordCount  

...More Stuff
```

The problem is that this VBA returns 5 for `rst.RecordCount` when it should return 4....

Comment: Formatted for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the following instruction is not optimal as it can fool you if you're in the case where your form's record source is a SQL query and not a table:

```
CurrentTableName = Screen.ActiveForm.RecordSource
```

So make sure that this instruction retruns the correct table name.

Secondly: using recordset.recordcount might not return the expected results depending on your cursor type and the datasource. From microsoft:

> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of
>   records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for
>   a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor;
>   and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on
>   the data source.

So to be sure you're always returning the correct amount of records, do a :

```
rst.movelast
```

prior to do the recordcount

Your code should work fine after those corrections.